# implementing custom completer, popup window steal the focus

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I need to implement custom completer, similar to `QCompleter` but containing customized widgets. I got stuck at the very beginning, I can't make the popup work as it should work. In the following example I attach a completer (well, just a plain widget) to the first line edit. The second line edit is there just to test the focus in/out behavior. The problem is that when the popup displays, it steals the focus from the line edit. But this is not what I want, I want to be able to keep typing in the line edit. I tried several other options as commented out in the code below, but non of them worked.

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QLineEdit>
#include <QHBoxLayout>
#include <QWidget>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QWidget container;
    QLineEdit editor;
    QLineEdit editor2;
    QHBoxLayout layout(&container);
    layout.addWidget(&editor);
    layout.addWidget(&editor2);

    QWidget completer; // or QWidget completer(&editor);?
    //completer.setFocusProxy(&editor); // tried this, but it does not help
    completer.setWindowFlags(Qt::Popup);

    // the following lines are an alternative to Qt::Popup but the window
    // does not close automatically, which is a problem 
    // e.g. when moving or resizing the parent window
    //completer.setAttribute(Qt::WA_ShowWithoutActivating);
    //completer.setWindowFlags(Qt::Tool | Qt::FramelessWindowHint);

    QObject::connect(&editor, &QLineEdit::textEdited,
         [&] {
                completer.resize(editor.width(), 100);
                completer.move(editor.mapToGlobal(QPoint(0, editor.height())));
                completer.show();
                // editor.setFocus(); // does not help either
             });

    container.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

How to implement custom completer?

UPDATE: From the docs, I read that "A popup widget is a special top-level widget that sets the Qt::WType_Popup widget flag, e.g. the QMenu widget. When the application opens a popup widget, all events are sent to the popup. Normal widgets and modal widgets cannot be accessed before the popup widget is closed."

So it seems that when I open a popup it automatically receives the events and therefore I have to forward the events to the line edit using `QCoreApplication::sendEvent(editor, event);` inside my `Completer::keyPressEvent`. This seems to work fine except the fact that the cursor in the line edit is not visible or not blinking.

Comment: Did you consider [`QCompleter::setCompleterMode()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcompleter.html#completionMode-prop) with [`QCompleter::InlineCompletion`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcompleter.html#CompletionMode-enum)?

Comment: Another idea: You may retrieve the popup widget with [`QCompleter::popup()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcompleter.html#popup) and then apply [`Widget::setFocusPolicy()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#focusPolicy-prop) with [`Qt::NoFocus`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#FocusPolicy-enum). Looking at this, I saw also [`QWidget::setFocusProxy()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#setFocusProxy) which seems to be worth to investigated as well.

Comment: I cannot use the standard Qt completer because the popup must inherit from `QAsbtractItemView`. And I need the popup behavior combined with a custom widget...

Answer (score 1):

Just apply this method to your completer widget:

```
setWindowFlags(Qt::Tool | Qt::FramelessWindowHint|Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint);
```

It works for me.